# Returning values to python from page.evaluate in Pyppeteer (Python Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, python, pyppeteer

I'm using Pypeteer to screen scrape a page and I have the following code which selects various elements.

```
foo = await page.evaluate("""
        var name = document.querySelectorAll("h2")[0].innerText
        var balance = document.querySelectorAll("h3")[0].outerText
        var liabilities = document.querySelectorAll("h3")[1].outerText

        return name,balance,liabilities
    
    """)

    name = foo[0]
    balance = foo[1]
    liabilities = foo[2]
```

What I would like to do, is to get the values of the various document.querySelector attributes (name, balance, liabilities) into those three python variables to then process them further down in the script.

The above code throws the following error:

```
pyppeteer.errors.ElementHandleError: Evaluation failed: SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
```

Not sure how to progress from this point. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[]` in javascript:

```js
return [name, balance, liabilities]
```